# What is wrong with my code? NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

What is wrong with the below code? It will throw NullPointerException while execution time.

```
public class Test
{
  public String method1()
  {
    return null;
  }
  public Integer method2()
  {
    return null;
  }
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
  {
    Test m1 = new Test();
    Integer v1 = (m1.method1() == null) ? m1.method2() : Integer.parseInt(m1.method1());
  }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(m1.method1());` - error

Comment: What is MyTest?

Comment: @WarwickMasson yes. MyTest m1 = new Test();

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @WarwickMasson sorry for my mistake. I wrongly typed. MyTest m1 = new MyTest();

Comment: Are you saying that is ***not*** in the code throwing the NPE?  Please copy/paste code rather than waste the time of people by forcing them to try and guess.

Comment: Why are people down voting..it is good question.

Comment: @ShivamKalra Looking at the comments, my guess is that a possible reason for downvotes was that uncompiled code was initially posted...

Comment: @alderath yes. it's my mistake. :-( Now, i corrected by code

Answer (score 9):

The type of a `a ? b : c` is the type of the last value `c`.  In this case it's an `int`.  This means that even though `b` is being chosen it is being unboxed and then re-boxed into an Integer.  As the value is null, this fails.

Here is a similar example which may help (or be more confusing)

```
Integer i = 1000;

// same as Integer j = Integer.valueOf(i == 1000 ? i.intValue() : 1000);
Integer j = i == 1000 ? i : 1000;
System.out.println(i == j);

Integer k = i == 1000 ? i : (Integer) 1000;
System.out.println(i == k);
```

prints

```
false
true
```

The reason the first result is false, is that expression has a type of `int` (the last argument) which means `i` is unboxed to be an `int` and reboxed so it can be assigned to the Integer.  This results in a different object (There are command line args which would increase the cache size and change this)  In the second example the type is `Integer` so it is not unboxed and the object is the same.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know: `This means that even though b is being chosen it is being unboxed and then re-boxed into an Integer`. Never stop to learn!

Comment: @mardavi Added an example which shows it is being unboxed and reboxed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. +1 Learnt something new today. Nice :) didn't knew that the result type is the type of `C`. Great answer, specially the code illustration.

Comment: @PeterLawrey clearly understand your explanation.thank you so much:-)

Answer (score 1):

parseInt returns int. That makes the compiler to unbox m1.method2() but it is null so it throws:

```
Integer v1 = (m1.method1() == null) ? m1.method2() : (Integer)Integer.parseInt(m1.method1());
```